# Blazor - SetParameters - why string parameter binding behaves differently from a complex type

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

Consider child component with string parameter and with a complex type parameter.

```
<Child Name="@strProperty" />
<Child Model="@compelexType" />
```

Assuming neither parameter has changed, calling StateHasChanged on the parent component causes the Child component with complex parameter to rerender, but not with string parameter.

See this demo: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wbYguGuA515uMYR742

How do you explain different behavior?

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rendering-conventions-for-componentbase): *"Components inherited from ComponentBase skip rerenders due to parameter updates if either of the following are true: ... All of the parameter values are of known immutable **primitive types**, such as int, **string**, DateTime, and **haven't changed** since the previous set of parameters were set, ..."*

Comment: I would accept this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rendering-conventions-for-componentbase):

> Components inherited from [`ComponentBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase) skip rerenders due to parameter updates if either of the following are true:
>
> - *All of the parameter values are of known immutable **primitive types**, such as `int`, **`string`**, `DateTime`, and **haven't changed** since the previous set of parameters were set.*
> - The component's [`ShouldRender`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.shouldrender) method returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer per se, I just need more space than in a comment.

I don't believe the quoted documentation fully explains the observed results.

> The document states:

By default, Razor components inherit from the ComponentBase base class, which contains logic to trigger rerendering at the following times:

1. After applying an updated set of parameters from a parent component.
2. After applying an updated value for a cascading parameter.
3. After notification of an event and invoking one of its own event handlers.
4. After a call to its own StateHasChanged method (see ASP.NET Core Razor component lifecycle).

These are all internal actions.  The first two occur after `SetParametersAsync` has been called on the component.  The last two from internal actions within the component.

Any child component activity, such as re-rendering, is triggered by the `Renderer` calling `SetParametersAsync`, not directly by the parent. The `Renderer` makes this decision based on detected changes to any child component `Parameter`'s.  So the reason the re-render occurs is because the `Renderer` is deciding that it's an object and not primitive type, nothing to do with `ComponentBase`.

To prove this I wrote a very basic component based on `IComponent` rather than `ComponentBase`.  It looks like this:

```cs
using Blazor.Starter.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blazor.Starter.Components.TestComponents
{
    public class ObjectTest : IComponent
    {
        [Parameter] public DataModel Model { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public int Value { get; set; }

        private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
        private int _renders;

        public void Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
        {
            _renderHandle = renderHandle;
        }

        public Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
        {
            parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
            _renders++;
            this.Render();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Render()
            => _renderHandle.Render(RenderComponent);

        private void RenderComponent(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
            builder.AddContent(1, $"Rendered {_renders}");
            builder.CloseElement();
        }

    }
}
```

If you set `Model` in the parent `SetParametersAsync` is called, if you only set `Value` it doesn't.  Same result.

Answer (score 0):

As @GSerg said in a comment: It's because the primitive property didn't change, so it does not update.