# Calling StateHasChanged on each child individually when ShouldRender is overrriden

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

GIVEN that I have bunch of child components

```
<Parent>
   <Child ref="children[0]" />
   <Child ref="children[1]"/>
   <Child ref="children[2]" />
</Parent>
```

THEN

is there any performance difference or side effect of calling StateHasChanged on each Child component  individually comparing to calling StateHasChanged on parent component?

Comment: I would hope not, since the whole idea is to have independent components. If you need to coordinate calls to `StateHasChanged` at the page level, that would be bad.

Comment: This is too open a question really - of course there are differences - but no-one can say what the precise effect on performance would be as it depends on how you write your components and what they do. What can be said is the there are some obvious differences, such as calling SHC on the parent will submit the parent and ALL its children to the render queue, while just calling SHC on each child will not submit the parent for a render. In general I try to keep each component responsible for its own rendering. In this case I would not have any UI in the Parent so it would never need to refresh.

Comment: @MisterMagoo ... Are you sure calling StateHasChanged() on parent causes child components to re-render?  If there are no changes in parameters being cascaded or passed down to the the child components then I don't think calling StateHasChanged() on parent component means that all child components automatically re-render.

Comment: Sure parameters are checked but that happens as part of the render batch

Comment: @NeilW: Even when parameters are not changed but there is at least one non primitive parameter, child components are rerendered. See my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800279/blazor-setparameters-why-string-parameter-binding-behaves-differently-from-a/67800626#67800626

Comment: @Liero Almost Exactly - the child Component can still return `false` from `ShouldRender` to prevent the full render happening, but t does still participate in the render tree processing up to that point.

Comment: @NeilW what I said it was "calling SHC on the parent will submit the parent and ALL its children to the render queue" - which is not the same as "calling StateHasChanged() on parent causes child components to re-render" at all.

Comment: Can I read somewhere about the "render queue"? I'm curious whether calling StateHasChanged individually has some inefficiency comparing to calling it once on parent Component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer: It doesn't really matter what strategy you use, only the differences between the virtual DOM and the RenderTree are passed to the actual DOM.  Everything else is just executed code.

A more complete but complicated answer:

First, understand the difference between `IComponent` and `ComponentBase`.  All components must implement `IComponent` -it's the interface the `Renderer` uses to communicate with a component.  `ComponentBase` is a Blazor implementation of `IComponent` and the default base component for Razor components.

Razor markup component gets pre-compiled into a C# class.  You can see them in the *obj* directory.

The first time your component gets passed to the `Renderer` by it's parent it:

1. Gets instantiated just like any standard C# object.
2. The `Renderer` adds it to the `RenderTree`.
3. The `Renderer` calls `Attach` and passes the component a `RenderHandle` which it stores.
4. The `Renderer` calls `OnParametersSet` passing in any requested parameters.

That's it, as defined by `IComponent`.  For any components inheriting from `ComponentBase` the standard well know event sequence is kicked off by `OnParametersSet`, including calling `StateHasChanged`.

`StateHasChanged` is a `ComponentBase` method.  It calls `RenderHandle.Render` passing the `RenderFragment` that represents the component.  Any new components in the `RenderFragment` go through the cycle above.  For any existing components, the Renderer:

1. Checks if the Component has any child components - these may have cascaded parameters.
2. Checks to see if any of the component's `Parameters` have changed.  For primitives that's easy, but if there are any objects it assumes they have changed.

If either is true it calls `OnParametersSet` on the component and passes in the appropriate parameters.

`RenderHandle.Render` stacks the `RenderFragment` on the Render Queue. When executed the Queue updates the virtual DOM held by the Renderer,  then runs the Diffing engine to discover and pass any DOM differences to the Client which updates the actual DOM in the browser.

I've tried to keep this succinct, but ....  Hopefully this helps a little in understanding the component and render process.

Comment: Where can I read more about the Render Queue? That's what I was looking for, but I haven't seen any mention about it in the blazor docs

Comment: I wrote and article a while ago - https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Blazor-Components.html.  My knowledge comes from exploring the dotnetcore code repo and writing components from scratch i.e. implementing `IComponent`.  You know the process writing, re-writing, refactoring,...